# Cant get open -a to work correctly with Adobe

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I am new to shell scripting and I am trying to open some pdf files with terminal on mac, so I can script it later, however I cannot get them to open in Acrobat or even Photoshop when I specify the application. I have tried both open -a Acrobat ~/filename/*.pdf and open -a "Adobe Acrobat 7.0 Professional" /(absolute url)/*.pdf, and variations thereof.

It works great when I try it with preview or textedit and opens fine when I just use open, except some open in preview. Is there something screwy with Adobe that s preventing me from targeting the application or am I missing something simple? Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT

After banging my head against a wall I found out that I was defining the absolute path wrong. I am not sure why it Acrobat and Photoshop do not need an absolute path when opening normally and does when specifying the application with -a but escaping the spaces in the path worked.

Example: /Applications/Adobe\ Acrobat\ 7.0\ Professional/Adobe\ Acrobat\ 7.0\ Professional.app/

Comment: Adobe is a company. The *application* is referred to as *Acrobat* or *Adobe Acrobat*.

Comment: Of course I am saying "Adobe" because it does not work in Photoshop either, as I stated in my post. Please at least read it if you are going to critique my post instead of actually contributing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `open` command is specific to Mac OSX. I've updated your tags to reflect that.

If the application you're opening is in `/Applications` directory, you do not need the path. Just the application name. You do not need the `.app` suffix. The case in the name isn't important, but the exact spelling is, and if you application contains any spaces, you need to enclose the application's name in quotation marks.

I don't have Acrobat or Photoshop on my system, but if they contain revision numbers in the name, or they have spaces, you need to include them. For example:

```
$ open -a "Adobe Acrobat 7.0 Professional/Adobe Acrobat 7.0 Professional" foo.pdf
```

(I have no idea of the *actual* name. I don't have Acrobat on my system, and I have no plans on downloading that piece of whine-ware (defined as software that demand you update it more often than you actually use it).

Comment: I thought I had to escape each space in the path name, but I must have been using the quotes around each file/folder instead of the entire path. Any idea why just using "Acrobat" doesn't work with the -a, because it does work if I just use the regular open command? Thank you for your reply and your assistance.